# vue + nuxt js - how to access context in a plugin for server side?

Tags: vue.js, plugins, nuxt.js

I like to know if there is a way to access in a plugin the context variables? Which other variables / objects exists apart from the "process" object? Unfortunately I could not found a clear description nor a reference about the "process" object at the [nuxt side](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/)

i.e. plugins/helper.js

```
const myHelper = {
  helpFunction(arg) {
    if (process.server) {
      ...
    }
    return ...;
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you export a function in your plugin, you will automatically have access to nuxt `context` as it's first argument ([docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#inject-into-context)):

```js
    export default (context, inject) => {
      context.app.helpFunction= (arg) => {
          if (process.server) {
             ...
          }
          return ...;
      }
    }
```

now you can use your helper function in any component like this:

```js
    this.$helpFunction(someArgs)...
```